# Can you constrain a column of one table with the column of another table?

Tags: sql

I am studing SQL I wanted to know how to restrict with check so the values possible values allowed are the values introduced in another column and another table.

First I create a table like this:

```
Create table table1(
  col1 numeric pk,
  col2 varchar,
  col3 varchar,
  ...);
```

Then you create a second table defined like this:

```
create table table2(
      col1 numeric pk,
      col2 numeric reference table1(col1),
      col3 varchar check (col3 in table1(col2))
     );
```

I assume that this will not work because there is no data in the columns when you define them. So I wanted to know if there is a method to do the same thing.

I hope I do not say anything complicated

1st edited. Okay, so I created a table and executed it. Now I executed it with posgres and tells me that:

org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «table1»

Position: 93

```
at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:133)

at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:577)

at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$1(SQLQueryJob.java:486)

at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:172)

at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:493)

at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:894)

at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:3643)

at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:118)

at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:172)

at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:116)

at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:4945)

at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)

at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: You already have one foreign key. Add another one.

Comment: Sorry, I have to edit the question because I see that it was porly written because part of the code was written as text. I hope that now this expllains better my question.

Comment: What is the error you would expect? Did you try?

Comment: Read my first comment one more time.

Comment: To markus, the error would be that it would not allow me to create the table and for jarlh, foreign keys are only valid to refer to primary keys. I do not know if you refer to something else

Comment: Which dbms are you using? A foreign key must reference a key, i.e. foreign key or unique constraint. (However, there are some products allowing a foreign key to reference a non-key as well.)

Comment: Hello jarlh I was using posgre SQL.